# Specifying a Thread's Name when using Task.StartNew

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to specify a Thread's name when using the `Task.StartNew` method

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(MyAction, TaskCreationOption.LongRunning, ??ThreadName??);
```

Comment: For what purpose do you even want to name your thread?

Comment: Actual Threads do (can) have names. But Tasks don't.

Comment: @Ron debugging!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not a Thread-name for sure.

Threads and tasks are not 1-to-1 related.

You can use the Task.Id to track it.

Comment: I have a long running task which means a new thread is created and I wanted to name it

Comment: No guarantees, just a Hint that could even be ignored. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx

Comment: No but I need it definately on another thread and thought I'd read if I specify LongRunning it will do that

Comment: The default scheduler does actually create a thread with the LongRunning option (in the current, could change in the future, implementation).  However, as Henk says a few comments above, _no guarantees_.

Comment: And that is what I have found but is the general consensus to go back to manually creating a thread and managing it myself?

Comment: @Jon: "... to manually creating a thread ... " - of course not.

Comment: @Jon: This is de-railing into an entirely different question,  un-answerable from the info in your post. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 43):

Well, this works:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "foo";
            Thread.Sleep(10000);   // Use Debug + Break to see it
        });
        task.Wait();
    }
}
```

There's a problem however, the threadpool thread gets recycled and won't change its name.  This can be confusing, you'll see it running later executing entirely different code.  Be sure to take note of this.  Your best bet is otherwise to use the Location column in the Debug + Windows + Threads window to find the task back.

Comment: Setting the Thread.Name property is only allowed when it's not set already, because Thread.Name is write-once! So a check for null before changing it could be required when the thread is recycled!
If you really need to, you could remember the "old" thread name and set it back to what it was before. That's not simple. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353349/thread-renaming) for more about this.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.  It's not as good as a name, but does help track the specific work for a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks use  the threadpool and a thread can be named only once.  What you can do is use a ThreadStatic variable. It will however live between tasks, so set it in every task again.

Answer (score -2):

You could write your own TaskScheduler which sets Thread.CurrentThread.Name when it puts a task on a thread. After the task is done your custom TaskScheduler can also clear Thread.CurrentThread.Name to avoid any confusion.

Comment: That is not possible actually - once the Name-Property of a Thread has been set it cannot be modified anymore.