# thread '<No Name>' has exited--want to give it a name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Given the following code,

```
Process Proc=null;
ProcessStartInfo DirectX=new ProcessStartInfo("dxsetup.exe", "/silent");
DirectX.WorkingDirectory="Tools\\directx";
Proc=Process.Start(DirectX);
```

I get `The thread '<No Name>' (0x1eec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).` in the output window of Visual Studio upon termination of the process.

I would like to change the text `"No Name"` to something descriptive, yet all I find online is for `Thread.Name` which doesn't seem to work for `Process` objects.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Building with C# .NET 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010. Running on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Things you start with `Process` does not work that way. Those threads you see stopping are likely ThreadPool threads that have had no work to do and are being destroyed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Seems like a formula based on guesswork to me.

Comment: @spender Not sure quite what you're implying, I'm looking to make the output window more descriptive.

Comment: @kmort : It appears to me that you've seen a thread ending and assumed that it's in some way related to the ending of your process. If this is so, it's merely a coincidence or an implementation detail that I would be very dubious about relying on as an indicator of the state of your program. The `Process` class offers better ways to trap the end of the process. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The Thread you see is the thread used by the process class to watch for the end of the process and throws the exited Event. Its managed by the process class so you have no chance to get at it. If your not interested in that event simply set [EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) to false and you are no longer bothered by the output window message.

Comment: @spender I've been using Process.WaitForExit(). It works just fine. I only wanted to see if I could make the output window easier to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are always plenty of threads running in your program that you didn't directly start yourself.  Like the threads in the .NET threadpool, the native Windows threadpool and the RPC threadpool, you'll see them exiting when the pool manager trims the pool.  The Process class itself uses tp threads, that's how the Exited event is raised for example.

You cannot name them, you didn't start them and there's no way to get a reference to such a thread.  Naming a threadpool thread [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8038572/17034) if it runs your code but it is a hack.

The easiest way to cut down on the noise is to right-click the Output window while you are debugging and untick "Thread Exit Messages".

Comment: After thinking about my question a bit more and some exploration in the debugger, it's actually a silly question. Process.Start() spins up A NEW PROCESS, not a thread. While those threads shutting down are definitely related to listening for the end of my process (as indicated by multiple comments above), there are in NO WAY the running process itself. I'll just turn off the "Thread Exit Messages" as Hans mentioned. Thanks All.