# Log4net C#4.0 [(null)] in output

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net

When I use log4net for logging in .NET4.0 I use the following code

LogManager declaration:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

And when used in code:

```
log.Info("My info text");
```

This outputs the following to the log-file:

```
2013-10-01 14:41:11,010 [3] INFO  MyNamespace.MyClass [(null)] - My info text
```

I am wondering what the **[(null)]** means and how I can remove/change it?

This is my config-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="log-file.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Just a little simplification. Instead of `LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);` just do `LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClassName));`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

***Fix***

To stop it appearing in the log remove `[%property{NDC}]` from the config file.

This happens because log4net automatically populates a context of information that might be useful for logging - in some cases this might result in a `null` value.

---

***log4net NDC***

This post explains how to use NDC: [When to use 'nested diagnostic context' (NDC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334367/when-to-use-nested-diagnostic-context-ndc)

In short log4net calls the static method `log4net.NDC.Push` to set the context of the the code.

You could for example set the NDC manually by running the following:

```
log4net.NDC.Push("context")
```

From that point forward outputting a log message will supply `%property{NDC}` as the string `context`.

---

***UPDATE:***

*`NDC.Push`* has been deprecated. [Alternatively, you can use `ThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push("context")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203102/1139105)

Answer (score 20):

if you just want the `(null)` to disappear you can also set [`log4net.Util.SystemInfo.NullText`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Util_SystemInfo_NullText.htm) to some other value like `""` or `string.Empty`, it will use that instead.